# There's no sound on Windows 10 after plugged in a 3.5mm jack for the second time. How can I fix it?

Tags: windows-10, audio, realtek-hd-audio

I have a 2.1 sound system, that doesn't have a headphone output, which I use for listening to music and headphones that I use for gaming. I often switched between the two and until recently, it worked. The first time I encountered this issue was about a month ago, right after I had to completely reinstall Windows 10 because it was unstable which wasn't solved by a factory reset.
So far I tried the following:

- Audio troubleshooter
- System file integrity check (sfc)
- System disk check (why not)
- `dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth`
- `dism /online /cleanup-image checkhealth`
- `dism /online /cleanup-image restorehealth`
- the Realtek HD Audio driver that came with Windows 10 and
- the version from the laptop’s manufacturer's site
- clean boot

How can I fix it?

Edit:
I had a Linux distro on one of my USB drives, so I tried to replicate the issue on it. Every time I unplugged and re-plugged the 3.5mm jack on that system, there still was soumd. So I think this is not a hardware issue.

Comment: Might I suggest just plug it in and out rapidly several times? In my experience sometimes jams happen in minijack.

Comment: There is no sound whatsoever? Or only in the 2.1 system?

Comment: @Mache No sound on the 3.5mm output (doesn't matter if it is the sound system or the headphones). If I unplug it, the built-in speakers will work.

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 Thanks for the suggestion. I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: If unplugging-plugging doesn't work, might I suggest a tip that used to work on older iPhones, way back when there were audio output issues with the 3.5mm jack? Place your mouth on the jack hole and *aspirate* (not blow) air through it. Granted, it's unpleasant, and if there is some dust or piece of lint inside the jack, it'll end up in your mouth, but it works every single time.

Comment: Have you tried to right-click on the loudspeaker icon in your taskbar and selecting the appropriate output?

Comment: @1NN There's only one output. There's not much of a choice there but I tried to select it. It didn't help.

Comment: @Didier unplugging and re-plugging didn't work. I had a Linux distro on one of my USB drives, so I tried to replicate the issue with it but I couldn't. Every time I plugged in the speakers or the headphones, it worked. I'll add this to the description.

Comment: @WeylynSavan While not relevant to your question, just an FYI regarding `DISM` and `SFC`: `DISM`'s `/RestoreHealth` should always be run prior to `SFC`, else running `SFC` is a waste of time and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` should be run before `/RestoreHealth`, else `/RestoreHealth` can fail due to a dirty Component Store _(the other two you listed are not needed - `/ScanHealth` || `/CheckHealth`)_

Comment: @JW0914 I only run those commands because I asked this at Microsoft's forum (which I know is useless but I did it anyway) and the 'technician' there instructed me to run them.

Comment: Have you tried in Control Panel -> Sound -> Manage Audio devices. Look if your 3.5mm jack is listed / or if sth changes when you plug / unplug your devices. If it IS listed, try in Properties to see if deactivating / reactivating helps. Through Properties you can also see the driver details and see if it's possible to update them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was caused by user error. I disabled Realtek HD Audio Manager at startup. After messing around a little, I remebered it and started digging around a little. Of course, it has no Start menu entry or desktop shortcut but I found it. After running `C:\Program Files\Realtek\Audio\HDA\RAVCpl64.exe`, the issue is gone.